# Convert string representing timestamp to date format inside python list

Tags: python

I have a list that contains a string that represents a timestamp which I need to convert to a date format, essentially stripping the time portion of the timestamp (which will later be inserted into mysql).  I've tried a number of different things, none of which are giving me the desired result.

```
from datetime import datetime
x = [[7, 25, '2018-09-30T06:45:00'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29T06:45:00']]

def convert(s):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    return date_object.date()

for i in x:
    new_list = [i[0], i[1], ]
    t = convert(i[2])
    new_list.append(t)
    print(new_list)
```

Results:

```
[7, 25, datetime.date(2018, 9, 30)]
[14, 18, datetime.date(2018, 9, 29)]
```

But if I just print the converted element of the list, I get the date format I need:

```
[...]
for i in x:
    t = convert(i[2])
    print(t)
```

Results:

```
2018-09-30
2018-09-29
```

My goal is to get a new list with the two original elements, plus the newly converted date:

```
old_list = [[7, 25, '2018-09-30T06:45:00'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29T06:45:00']]

new_list = [[7, 25, '2018-09-30'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
old_list = [[7, 25, '2018-09-30T06:45:00'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29T06:45:00']]

new_list = []

for lst in old_list:
    last_item = lst[-1]
    lst[-1] = last_item[:10]
    new_list.append(lst)

print(new_list)  #[[7, 25, '2018-09-30'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29']]
```

```
from datetime import datetime
x = [[7, 25, '2018-09-30T06:45:00'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29T06:45:00']]

def convert(s):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    return date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for idx,item in enumerate(x):
    x[idx][-1] = convert(item[2])

print(x) # [[7, 25, '2018-09-30'], [14, 18, '2018-09-29']]
```

Comment: Using enumerate worked for my purpose, thank you.  .append was creating the list correctly, but I was getting a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" error when trying to insert the tuple into mysql.

Comment: just copy paste this to create newlist of tuple https://pastebin.com/SZMFnUXq you were appending only date to newlist and also resetting the list again and again in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply parse the date to a string in the `convert` functions return statement:

```
return str(date_object.date())
```

Or use `strftime` to parse the date to a string with the desired format:

```
return date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```